# Enable / disable cookie based login in Yii framework on login

Tags: php, cookies, yii

I am working on a web application where the user can choose a remember me check box.

If user chooses remember me, then cookie based login will be enabled and I will use this code to enable the cookie:

```
    Yii::app()->user->login($identity,24*3600*7,true);
```

If user does not choose remember me, then cookie based login will be disabled and I will use this code to disable the cookie:

```
    Yii::app()->user->login($identity,24*3600*7,false);
```

Here, the third parameter is allowautoLogin as described in [documents](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#login-detail)..

Am i wrong ... ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use this if user checked the remember me checkbox:

```
Yii::app()->user->login($identity, 24*3600*7);
```

and this if he didn't:

```
Yii::app()->user->login($identity, 0);
```

Make sure that you allowed auto login in your config file:

```
'components' => array(
    'user' => array(
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
    ),
    // ...
),
```

Comment: i have read that if we input 0 user will be login for the preconfigured time described in yii ..

Comment: Where have you read it? Because documentation states that 0 means until the user closes the browser. Anyway, "it's not working" is terrible problem description.

Comment: when i try it in firefox it worked for me... byt in chrome .. it is not working for me.. but thanks.. it is working om firefox.. can i delete all cookies after user log in to system if cookie login is disabled ...(remember me unchecked..)